# Why does my web app pause after making a couple of requests to push an item to my mongodb database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

A part of my react app involves a user to type in something in and after they press the button to submit, it gets added to the database. Part of my mongodb schema involves "sessions" which is an array. Here's my schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    googleId: String,
    displayName: String,
    sessions: Array
});
```

It works and gets updated but if I try submitting around 6 or 7 items to the database, it stops and when i try to refresh the page, it takes like a minute or two to actually refresh. Why is it doing this? Is there a limit on how many times I can update the database per minute or something? Here's the post route

```
app.post('/api/addToDatabase', (req, res) => {
        //console.log(req.body)
        User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) {
            user.sessions.push(req.body);
            user.save();
        })
    })
```

Comment: You never end the `res`ponse.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thank you so much!! just looked up ending response and that got it to work. Did not know you needed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client sends a request to the server, and the server sends a response. If the response doesnt arrive, it will timeout after a while and that is what you are seeing. Or you just tell the server to answer immeadiately:

```
  res.end("done :)");
```

Comment: @benoit no worries :)